# How to use parameters with NODEJS and JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am doing a project in NODEJS and I am using a libraries for DICOM files but it turns out that I need to send parameters from one view to another, but that I have achieved, but I need to use those parameters that I receive with NODEJS in a function with JQUERY, .NET and there are some variables flames viewbag is there something similar here? How do I make a jquery function receive parameter from a NODEJS

Here the code

```
function loadStudyJson(studyViewer, studyId)
  {
      $.getJSON('javascripts/' + studyId, function(data) {
      // Load the first series into the viewport
          $('#wadoURL').val();
          var stacks = [];
          var currentStackIndex = 0;
          var seriesIndex = 0;
          data.seriesList.forEach(function(series) {
              var stack = {
                  seriesDescription: series.seriesDescription,
                  stackId : series.seriesNumber,
                  imageIds: [],
                  seriesIndex : seriesIndex,
                  currentImageIdIndex: 0,
                  frameRate: series.frameRate
              }
```

In the code there is a function which obtains a list of records of a file, json and from there it obtains a series object where it obtains all its data, then I want to obtain that data of NODEJS and not of JSON file, Connect to database and get the data I want but how do I make the function in JQUERY use the PARAMETERS OF NODEJS

Sorry for my english

Comment: The English is fine, the code that is missing is the problem

Comment: I already added it